# Ruby get object keys as array

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby, if I have an object like this

```
{"apple" => "fruit", "carrot" => "vegetable"}
```

How can I return an array of just the keys?

```
["apple", "carrot"]
```

Comment: Your object is a Hash, so you can use `keys` method like `{"apple" => "fruit", "carrot" => "vegetable"}.keys`.  For more info visit http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/

Answer (score 245, accepted):

```
hash = {"apple" => "fruit", "carrot" => "vegetable"}
array = hash.keys   #=> ["apple", "carrot"]
```

it's that simple

Answer (score 20):

An alternative way if you need something more (besides using the `keys` method):

```
hash = {"apple" => "fruit", "carrot" => "vegetable"}
array = hash.collect {|key,value| key }
```

obviously you would only do that if you want to manipulate the array while retrieving it..

Answer (score 6):

Like taro said, `keys` returns the array of keys of your Hash:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-keys

You'll find all the different methods available for each class.

If you don't know what you're dealing with:

```
 puts my_unknown_variable.class.to_s
```

This will output the class name.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `keys` method: `{"apple" => "fruit", "carrot" => "vegetable"}.keys == ["apple", "carrot"]`